# Gatsby, Stripe: 決済ボタン実装をしようとしたら 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined'と出る

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-jsx, gatsby

[Gatsby公式ドキュメント](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ecommerce-tutorial/#setting-up-a-serverless-function-in-aws-lambda)にて、ECサイト構築チュートリアルに沿って開発をしています。
ただ、checkout.jsをチュートリアルの通りに書くと、以下のエラーが出て、画面全体が真っ白になります。

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined
The above error occurred in the <Checkout> component:
The above error occurred in the <LocationProvider> component:
GET http://localhost:8000/.../src/components/checkout.js 404 (Not Found)
```

特に `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined` と404 errorがいくつも出ています。

念のため、ほかのファイルはCSS-in-JS library, styled-componentsを使用しているので書き換えて見ましたが、ファビコンだけ表示されるようになり、エラー文は `Uncaught Error: Thestyleprop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.` になっただけで、画面表示は白いままです。

index.jsファイルも、自分が書いていたコードから、チュートリアル記事と全く同じコードにしてみましたが、変化はありませんでした。
checkout.jsのコンポーネントを読み込まず、無効化するとほかは問題なく表示されるのですが、何か解決策はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
public/index.html の直下に以下の内容を書き込むと反映されました。

```
<script src="checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```